# Blinking dash after choosing "Try and Install Ubuntu" on Ubuntu 22.04 installation GRUB screen

Tags: boot, usb-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my 4GB laptop, but after I clicking "Try and Install Ubuntu", the screen only show blinking dash in the top left corner. After that, my laptop suddenly turns off, and installation can't be continued.

[image: Since the GRUB become like this since 20.10 version, the USB Drive can't boot to Ubuntu, and just hang.]

Since the GRUB become like this since 20.10 version, the USB Drive can't boot to Ubuntu installer, and just hang after blinking.

My question is, can I rid this?, because the newer version of Ubuntu can't be installed on my laptop properly when at GRUB screen.

My laptop is Acer Aspire 4738Z with Intel Core i3 M380 processor.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO prior to write to media? and since you can't boot & verify the write of ISO to media on that device, did you verify the write of media on another device?  How long did you wait?  (*there are a few devices that due to firmware bugs, can take >12 minutes to boot 22.04 media unless the ISO is written a specific way to counter this firmware bug*)

Comment: Yes, I do it, but it has no effect. The laptop can't boot to GUI installer

Comment: Instead it just display a blinking dash in the top left corner, and become turns off.

Comment: Any help?......

Comment: The build of ISOs was changed after 20.04 (*you've added detail that this impacts 20.10 and later*), so is the software you write the ISOs capable of writing media later than 20.10?  If it just clones the ISO to media it didn't require change; however if using other features you need updated ISO writing software to deal with anything later than 20.04 due to the changes.